# How do I know whether my laptop supports 40MHz or 80MHz channel width?

Tags: wireless-networking

I am reading some introductions about WiFi and this is the last thing confusing me.

From https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202068 :

> ## 5GHz channel width
>
> ...
>
> For best performance and reliability, enable support for all channel
> widths. This allows devices to use the largest width they support,
> which results in optimal performance and compatibility. **Not all client
> devices support 40MHz channels, so don't enable 40MHz-only mode.
> Devices that support only 20MHz channels can't connect to a Wi-Fi
> router in 40MHz-only mode. Similarly, don't enable 80MHz-only mode, or
> only clients capable of 802.11ac will be able to connect.** Routers that
> don't support 40MHz or 80MHz channels do support 20MHz channels.

So how do I know whether my laptop supports 40MHz or 80MHz channel width?

Comment: Be careful about "40 MHz only" – as far as I know it's not an officially permitted mode in APs (they're supposed to only have "20 only" and "20/40 auto"), and on APs which do have a similar-sounding mode it can actually mean the old proprietary "SuperG" or "40 MHz Turbo" mode which is incompatible with the standard dual-channel 40 MHz mode.

Comment: Examine the specs of the device or its wireless adapter.

Comment: How would anyone know that if you don't put your wireless adapter/card model in the question? At the very least put the **laptop make & model** into the question so someone can find the information.

Answer (score 2):

802.11ac introduced the 80MHz channel width, and everything that supports AC supports the 80MHz width.

If your AP has an 80MHz-only mode, enabling it would disable your older devices (from before about 2013 or so) that only support 802.11n and earlier.